# How to get access token for access Pinterest Api

Tags: api, pinterest

I have Googled and searched on stackoverflow but could not find the answer.

I am writing an app, and this needs access to the Pinterest API.
This is my github repo: https://github.com/kellan/pinterest.api.php

```
$p = new Pinterest_API();
$p->fetch_access_token($client_id, $client_secret, $username, $password);
$resp = $p->some_api_call($args);
```

But i dont know where to find $client_id and $client_secret?

Comment: @Emil doubtful, seeing as the github repo he is linking to wasn't developed by Pinterest, it's 3rd party, Kellan Elliott-McCrea's.

Answer (score 2):

Go here, click ***Generate***, and get an access token: https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/access_token/

Example: get statuses using: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/pins/?access_token=TOKEN&fields=id,creator,note&limit=2

See docs for extra parameters and requests: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the Pinterest API has been taken down. I even got a take-down notice on my Pinterest Chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, Pinterest API has been taken down. All my apps were affected as well.

This v1 api link now only shows hyphen, dash on its count

http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=receiveCount&url=http://facebook.com

We can only wait till its back. I bookmarked your question and will try to update you when its back.

Comment: Nice, thanks for notifying us that it works again, +1 for that ;)

Comment: Hey Fedmich I need some pointers on accessing pinterest through api..any pointers? specially related to search

Comment: Hey Sudh, at the moment, there are still no official docs for Pinterest API. this is undocumented and was taken from looking at their pinterest button.