# Getting all pins of a specific user Pinterest

Tags: android, pinterest

Hey i'm trying to get all pins for a specific user from pinterest  API in android app
  but as i see for now there is no public Api after searching i found this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194892/how-to-obtain-pinterest-v3-api-key-or-access-token)   which contain an end point for fetching all pins of specific user `http://widgets.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/users/eecolor/pins/`
and this works perfectly but it doesn't contain the pin creating date.
Also i have checked the official website which contain a [sample response](https://developers.pinterest.com/sample_responses/pins/) for pins list and the data contain creation date

so how i can do this,is there any extra field should i added to the previous endpoint
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain scraping from here:
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/**[put-pin-id-here]**/

Ex. https://www.pinterest.com/pin/1234565787899/

See the page code:

meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-05-19T10:31:33"/

Comment: Thanks for you help but i want to retrive all pins at once and i want json response for that

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is no way to get pinterest pins from specific page unless you are the the admin of the page, but in this case you can use this url for using rest Api

```
"https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/pins/?access_token=token&fields=id%2Curl%2Cnote%2Ccreated_at%2Cimage&limit=10
```

and the access token could be generated from here

```
https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/access_token
```

Regards