# Pinterest login through app

Tags: ios, pinterest

Whenever I try to authenticate with app the following msg comes:

```
{"status": "failure", "code": 283, "host": "coreapp-ngapi-prod-7c03bdd4", "generated_at": "Thu, 06 Aug 2015 08:02:11 +0000", "message": "The authorization grant is invalid", "data": "Invalid Application ID"}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please submit your Podfile and a few lines of code showing where and how you invoke  the Pinterest API.

Comment: >I have used this 
pod "PinterestSDK", :git => "git@github.com:pinterest/ios-pdk.git"
> In app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
[PDKClient configureSharedInstanceWithAppId:APP ID];
>In my view controller 

 NSArray *permission =@[PDKClientReadPublicPermissions,PDKClientWritePublicPermissions];
    [[PDKClient sharedInstance] authenticateWithPermissions:permission withSuccess:^(PDKResponseObject *responseObject) {
        NSDictionary *dict =responseObject.parsedJSONDictionary;
        NSLog(@"%@",dict);
    } andFailure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];

Comment: A little late, but developers.pinterest.com/manage is for the old API. You need to create an app at developers.pinterest.com/apps/ if you want to use the SDK and the new API

Comment: I have also tried this out weeks ago but no reply come up from there side.

Comment: Did the proposed answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The message is pretty explicit: `Invalid Application ID`.

Have you added the URL Type?

[image]

Using this initializer:

```
PDKClient.configureSharedInstanceWithAppId("0000")
```

and this OAuth:

```
let permission = [PDKClientReadPublicPermissions]
PDKClient.sharedInstance().authenticateWithPermissions(permission,
    withSuccess: { (pdk :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in
        println("success PDKResponseObject: \(pdk)")
    }) { (err :NSError!) -> Void in
        println("error NSError: \(err)")
    }
```

and assuming your `client_id` is correct, you should be in business.

Comment: how to get a valid application id

Comment: I have created app from link
https://developers.pinterest.com/manage/
clicking on Add new app button, It provided me with App ID :-1446466

using this api give me the above msg
https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?client_id=1446466&redirect_type=js&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.pinterest.com%2Ftools%2Faccess_token%2F&response_type=token&scope=read_public%2Cwrite_public

Comment: sir I have done all these steps my question is my app id is not working,I think it is not approved by pinterest team. please help me how can my app id be valid

Comment: I have also gone through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194892/how-to-obtain-pinterest-v3-api-key-or-access-token but still no success

Comment: @SandhyaRathi - I'm facing same problem. Can you please provide me more information if you get solution.

Comment: @MehulS- I still not got any solution.

Comment: hi @SandhyaRathi now have you solve this? B'coz i also facing this problem from many days.

Comment: Got solution........ Today got email from Pinterest team, app id is now generating Happy Coding...............

Comment: @SandhyaRathi can you please help me? I have put my app in reviewing and still not approve and not even any mail and my app status is panding so can i test my app integration without app approve?

Comment: Short answer: no. It took over 3 weeks for Pinterest to respond the first time around.